# Postgres Debugger cannot be configured in Windows 11

Tags: postgresql, debugging

I am trying to configure the debugger in PostgreSQL 14.2 / PGAdmin 4. I change the postgresql.conf to `shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'`. The location of the file is correct.
When I check the configuration from PGAdmin4, 'shared_preload_libraries' does not show up.
I can add the extension pldbgabpi, but no debugger can be seen.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

on Windows debugger turns on in somewhat tricky way indeed. I've read tons of manuals and advises, none of them worked for me at Windows 10. What finally let me get the so long expected message   [screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpwDa.png)  is a set of simple steps, which are:

1. complete uninstall of existing PostgreSQL server and all related
   software;
2. fresh installation of new server and required
   complementary software;
3. making sure that file named 'plugin_debugger.dll' is present in exactly 'lib' directory of new installation (it's important as 'lib' means to be a '$libdir' below);
4. re-enabling of target DB within server; adding PlPgSQL
   extension to the DB [screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9F5L.png);
5. changing one line in the block 'Shared Library Preloading' of the 'postgresql.conf' file located in installation directory as below:

> 

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll' # (change requires restart)
#local_preload_libraries = ''
#session_preload_libraries = ''
#jit_provider = 'llvmjit'   # JIT library to use
```

6. re-starting the PostgreSQL server.

I expect it to be the same way with any newer versions of server at whatever version of Windows. Please let know if it helps in your case!

Comment: On my windows installation I also had to edit the line in the conf file as below:
dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'  (It was commented out before)